# How do I use a let within a do block in ghci?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm trying to create a do block interactively in ghci. As long as I don't define a variable with in block, it's fine:

```
Prelude>let a = do putStrLn "test"; putStrLn "other test"
Prelude>
```

but I can't figure out how to define a let construction in the do block interactively without getting a parse error:

```
Prelude> let a = do let b = 5; putStrLn $ show b

<interactive>:2:40:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
```

Obviously

```
let a = do
     let b = 5
     putStrLn $ show b
```

is entirely fine in a Haskell source file. I'm just having trouble figuring out how to translate that to ghci.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
let a = do let { b = 5 } ; print b
```

The `let` block can contain multiple declarations so you have to tell GHCi when they're done - that's what the brackets are for in this line.

By the way, you can use `print` for `putStrLn . show`.

Answer (score 13):

```
:help

 <statement>                 evaluate/run <statement>    
:{\n ..lines.. \n:}\n        multiline command
```

You can type **:{** to start a multiline command, and type **:}** to end it.

So just do

```
 Prelude> :{
 Prelude| let a = do
 Prelude|     let b=5
 Prelude|     putStrLn $ show b
 Prelude| 
 Prelude| :}
```

Be careful with layout (indentation/whitespace).  Otherwise you can get parse errors in apparently correct code.

For example the following will **NOT** work because the indentation isn't deep enough:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let a = do
Prelude|    let b=5
Prelude|    putStrLn $ show b
Prelude| 
Prelude| :}
```

It will lead to a parse error like this:

```
<interactive>:50:4: parse error on input ‘let’
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought that putting braces in would be fine, but this doesn't parse:

```
ghci> let a = do {let b = 5; putStrLn (show b)}
```

You can always take the multiline approach, which does work:

```
ghci> :{
ghci| let a = do let b = 5
ghci|            putStrLn $ show b
ghci| :}
```

Comment: @ДМИТРИЙМАЛИКОВ Yeah, I wasn't saying it worked! I edited to leave a comment to the effect that I knew the original answer didn't work, while I was changing the answer to something that *does* work! Should have tried running it in GHCI before posting the answer :)

Comment: You didn't put in enough braces.

Comment: @augustss What is this, Java?

Answer (score 1):

I landed here because I had the same question, but yatima2975's answer reminded me of how each let-block can have multiple bindings, so I tried the below and indeed it works.

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.8.3: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> do { let { x = 1; y = 2 }; putStrLn (show (x, y)) }
(1,2)
```